# How do I make progress bar while downloading file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6, tqdm

I'm using tqdm to monitor the downloading of files in my python programs but it doesn't show the progress bar.
I have this code:

```
from tqdm import *
import requests
url = "https://as2.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/520055aa72618571e4ce34b434e328b615570838-144p__58945.mp4"
name = "video"
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192), r.headers.get("content-length")):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                # f.flush()
```

But when I run it, it doesn't show me a progress bar, it shows me this:

```
763499: 94it [00:00, 192.31it/s]
```

I tried this code too:

```
from tqdm import *
import requests
url = "https://as2.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/520055aa72618571e4ce34b434e328b615570838-144p__58945.mp4"
name = "asdasdjk"
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk, bar in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192), r.headers.get("content-length"),tqdm(range(0,int(r.headers.get("content-length")))):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                # f.flush()
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    for chunk, bar in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192), r.headers.get("content-length"),tqdm(range(0,int(r.headers.get("content-length")))):
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no code in the first sample that would display a progress bar.  Why are you expecting that?

Comment: @JohnGordon So, why it doesn't show any progress bar? How do I make one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from tqdm import *
import requests
url = "https://as2.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/520055aa72618571e4ce34b434e328b615570838-144p__58945.mp4"
name = "video"
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        pbar = tqdm(total=int(r.headers['Content-Length']))
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                pbar.update(len(chunk))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your kind help! But can you explain more about this?

Comment: you are not updating the arguments right. Your same code works if you change your for loop like ```for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size= 8192), total=math.ceil(int(r.headers.get("content-length", 0))//8192))```

Comment: or you could combine different lines and get:
```with (
    requests.get(url, stream=True) as r,
    open(file, 'wb') as f,
    tqdm(total=int(r.headers['Content-Length'])) as pbar
):  
    r.raise_for_status()
    for chunk in r.iter_content():
        f.write(chunk)
        pbar.update(len(chunk))
```
but you do end up with a zero-sized file in this case if the connection fails. sad comments don't preserve linebreaks. anyway go with the original answer, it's fine.