# Downloading large files with python and keeping track of download progress

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I am trying to programatically download the Bitcoin time series while outputting the download status. I found a lot of online material related to my question, and I was basically copying the code from the accepted answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests), but for some reason it doesn't work. It starts downloading but after one or two minutes, the download suddenly stops. Here is my code:

```py
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

uri2 = "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/bitstampUSD.csv.gz"
with requests.get(uri2, stream=True) as r:
    total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
    with open("data.csv.gz", "wb") as file:
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), position=0, leave=True, total=total_length):
            if chunk:
                file.write(chunk)
                # I also tried adding file.flush() here, but the result is the same
```

Output:

```py
  0%|
| 271787/278309025 [00:28<7:58:27, 9685.15it/s]
```

Does anyone know why it is not working?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Probable solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796119/2052575